# CodeIgniter -> Shopify API. How to log in via OAuth via the CLI? Using shopify-api-php

Tags: php, oauth, shopify, codeigniter-4, shopify-api

I have been racking my brain for ages here - if somebody could enlighten me I would be extremely grateful.

I'm trying to perform a standard OAUTH login, exactly as per the docs here:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php

I have the api key, api secret key, host name etc. I am invoking the action using the command line - there is no web interface. I am running the application locally and using Session storage as there are no web cookies as I am not using a web browser.

Where I'm tripping up is on the 'callback' function - this doesn't seem to do anything. I am calling `Context::initialize` and `OAuth::begin(...` without issue but that is where things trip up.

I have a corresponding route set up '/auth/callback' which I believe should be invoked once the server returns a response to the initial login request which then provides the code, hmac values etc. needed to validate the session, but nothing happens.

I need to call `OAuth::callback(...` from within this callback function.

```
    Context::initialize(
        apiKey: config('ShopifyConfig')->api_key,
        apiSecretKey: config('ShopifyConfig')->api_secret_key,
        scopes: config('ShopifyConfig')->api_scopes,
        hostName: config('ShopifyConfig')->host_name,
        sessionStorage: new FileSessionStorage(),
        apiVersion: config('ShopifyConfig')->api_version,
    );

    $redirectUrl = OAuth::begin(
        shop: config('ShopifyConfig')->host_name,
        redirectPath: '/auth/callback', // doesn't do anything!
        isOnline: false,
        setCookieFunction: function (OAuthCookie $cookie) {
            $_SESSION['cookie'][] = [
                'name' => $cookie->getName(),
                'value' => $cookie->getValue(),
                'expire' => $cookie->getExpire(),
                'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
                'httpOnly' => $cookie->isHttpOnly(),
            ];
            return true;
        }
    );


public function logIn(Request $request)
{
    OAuth::callback(...)

    // Routes file

    $routes->get('/auth/callback', 'Home::logIn');
    $routes->post('/auth/callback', 'Home::logIn');
    $routes->cli('/auth/callback', 'Home::logIn');
```

Comment: You're missing the fact, that requiring user interaction is one of the basic principles of OAuth. It is not _made_ to be performed using CLI only. The callback URL gets invoked in the user's browser, by Shopify redirecting back to it.

Comment: There are tools like https://github.com/cloudentity/oauth2c that allow CLI-driven interactions that you can wrap into a shell-script and invoke the required PHP code from with a valid token.